# Not generating a PDF documents using CutePDF writer in windows service application C#

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-services

I converted text files to PDF documents using **CutePDF Writer printer** in windows forms application.It's working as expected but same block of code I used in c# windows service application to convert text files to PDF files.I'm not getting any exceptions while executing the code and not generating any PDF documents.

**I created the following registry key settings for CutePDF writer**

**Setting the display mode:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CutePDF Writer\BypassSaveAs
(0 = show Save as dialog box after spooling, 1 = do not show Save as dialog box.)
(This value is of type REG_SZ, not REG_DWORD)

**Setting the filename:**

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CutePDF Writer\OutputFile
(Use the key above to set the output file for the PDF. A full pathname
(e.g. d:\your folder\your file.pdf) is required.)

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with CutePDF Writer - but: as which user is the service running?

To clarify this: if the service runs as LocalService, the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER is not the same as the one from loged in user.

If that is the case, try HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19 instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: Should be a comment, with 25 rep you should know this by now... probably best to copy it and put it as a comment and delete this answer. If you have a solution, undelete it and edit it.

Comment: @JeremyThompson "probably best to copy it and put it as a comment" gives the impression that you (with 50k rep) are not aware that this would only be possible with 50 rep or more.